# О рекламном тексте

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, смысл

**Текст рекламного плаката:**

**Кто** ищет кухню, **тот** в Леруа Мерлен!

Почему-то этот текст мне не кажется удачным, но что с ним не так?

Насколько правилен выбор местоимения ***тот***, может быть, лучше использовать местоимение ***тому***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Тому" - не подойдёт здесь. Вероятнее всего, тот, кто ищет кухню,  уже в Леруа Мерлен,  и если вы ищете тоже самое,  следуйте за "теми", а то разберут.
 В рекламных слоганах зачастую используются подобные намёки. Это называется нлп - нейролингвистическое программирование.

Comment: Лучше, наверное,  запрограммировать на покупку, а не на поиски.

Comment: Ищущий кухню на покупку уже запрограммирован. Осталось указать ему нужное место и намекнуть, - ещё немного, и ты опоздаешь.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Кто ищет кухню, тому (следует пойти) в Леруа Мадлен.
Вежливый совет-приглашение.

Вариант 2. Кто ищет кухню, тот (уже находится) в Леруа Мадлен.
Крутая заявка на безальтернативность Леруа Мадлен. Лаконичность тоже крутая. Я бы выразился так: *Кто ищет кухню, тот ищет ее в Леруа Мадлен*.

Comment: Во-первых, краткость мне здесь не представляется сестрой таланта,  так как  грамматика неполного предложения не сразу воспринимается на слух. Во-вторых, искать - это еще не значит найти. Может быть, поищут, поищут и уйдут в другой магазин. Написали бы так: Кому нужна кухня, тот покупает ее в Леруа Мерлен!

Comment: Мне это краткость тоже не по душе. Но рекламщики должны постоянно искать новые формы, избитые обороты не привлекают полупателя.

Comment: Мне их поиски сначала вообще показались  элементарной неграмотностью,  то есть неумением выбрать нужный падеж.  И слово "ищет" уж точно  рекламу не украшает, здесь результат желательно обозначить, а не процесс.

Comment: Это как сказть. По-моему, призыв "Заходите посмотреть" завлекает лучше, чем "Приходите покупать".

Comment: А "Все ищут у нас" внушает больше доверия, чем "Все покупают у нас".

Comment: Ну ладно,  пусть будет по-вашему, но я к ним не пойду. Не люблю ходить и искать.